# Is the colormap conversion of openCV linear?

Tags: opencv, colormap

I have a gray scale image (i.e. 1 channel). I am using the opencv function applyColorMap() to improve the visualization. For example, if I have the code below

```
applyColorMap(imgGray, imgOut, COLORMAP_RAINBOW);
```

Somebody does know if the colormap conversion is linear?

[image]

[image: image description]
<sub>(source: [opencv.org](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/_images/colorscale_rainbow.jpg))</sub>

Comment: I cant get what do you mean by Linear? You are seeing the Color Values with respect to the Grey Levels. If you want different color's go for different Color Maps.

Comment: I suggest you to check the mathematics formula of each conversion. Most of the colour spaces are linear transforms from RGB

Comment: @dervish The thing is that I didn't find the conversions openCV used

Comment: check this: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colormaps used by the opencv function: applyColorMap have a linear relation between them. They are based on [GNU Octave / Matlab](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/colormaps.html?highlight=applycolormap) colormaps

> Graphics functions that use pseudocolor - mesh, surf, pcolor, and others - map a color matrix, c, whose values are in the range [cmin, cmax], to an array of indices, k, in the range [1, m]. The values of cmin and cmax are either min(min(c)) and max(max(c)), or are specified by caxis. The mapping is linear, with cmin mapping to index 1 and cmax mapping to index m. The indices are then used with the colormap to determine the color associated with each matrix element. [reference](https://www3.nd.edu/~dtl/cheg258/notes/doc/colormap.html)